# Object does not match target type with SetValue using Type

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm trying to dynamically build set objects based on a user input document.  For some reason SetValue is throwing Object does not match target type, despite that it does.

Is what im trying to achieve even possible?

```
private void MapProp(string prop, string invalue)
    {
           var currType = _userAssembly.GetType(_className);

            var property = currType.GetProperty(prop, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            var value = Convert.ChangeType(invalue, property.PropertyType);

            property.SetValue(styleType, value, null);
        }
    }
```

Currently its attempting to map to said object:

```
 public class TestObject: ITestObj
{
 public string PropertyA {get;set;}
 public string PropertyB {get;set;}
}
```

Calling Code

```
 MapProp("PropertyA", "testValue");
```

and the getType classname = .Assembly.TestObject

Comment: The code that you're showing doesn't include anything about the target type, nor the source type. We can't help you based on what you've included.

Comment: updated with more info, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@user4550364 ,I dont know what does your _user assembly does ,so I am gonna put my sample code ,this might help you to adapt the idea to your code.This is also an example of late binding.

Class file

```
public class TestObject: ITestObj
{
 public string PropertyA {get;set;}
 public string PropertyB {get;set;}
 void Print(string PropertyA,string PropertyB)
    {
//Assuming that interface ITestObj has this method definition and hence implementing here.
     }
}
```

Main code

```
using System.Reflection;

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Assembly executingassembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            Type TestObjecttype = executingassembly.GetType("ur_namespace.TestObject");

            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(TestObjecttype );

            string[] parameters = new string[2];
            parameters[0] = "PropertyA ";
            parameters[1] = "PropertyB ";
            //To get properties
            PropertyInfo[]  properties = TestObjecttype .GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
              {
           Console.WriteLine(property.PropertyType.Name+" "+property.Name);
               }
            MethodInfo method = customertype.GetMethod("Print");
            //Object created ,now invoke using its instance
            string printMethodInvoked= (string)method.Invoke(instance, parameters);
           Console.WriteLine(printMethodInvoked);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```